# Yahoo is taking over my Google search from my Safari on my Mac

Tags: macos, safari, malware

In Safari Preferences, *Google* is my Default Search Engine; New Windows and New Tabs are set to *Homepage*.

However, recently whenever I Google something, I click on my choice and I end up on Yahoo Search.  Sometimes I get `search.epolife.com`.

This is very frustrating, I do not want to go to a new search of Yahoo, I like my Google. How can I regain control of Safari?

Answer (score 6):

I found my answer in this YouTube video: [how to get rid of searchbar redirect in safari](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FjTmtxRlL8).

In Safari's Preferences, select **Extensions**.  There was the epolife. I **deleted the epolife extension**, quit and relaunched Safari and came back in. After that I no longer have this problem.

Comment: Mark it as solved. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you managed to get such an extension installed into Safari accidentally, you are also likely to have other malware on your Mac. Get a good malware removal tool to check your whole Mac (Malwarebytes, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Safari had the same problem. When I looked at installed extensions, I found one called "Smart Search" that I had never installed. 
I uninstalled it, and BINGO...Yahoo gone! possibly a Malware from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit on my Mac was the extension, AnySearch 1.2.3.  I When to Safari > Preferences > Extensions and uninstalled it.  Now, I'm back to Google.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. My search bar was set to Google. I couldn’t figure out the problem until:

- go to your Safari Preferences
- click “Extensions”
- if there is an extension named “Search It!” or anything else that you didn’t sign up for in there, *delete it!*

Hopefully this is helpful